# Vespa: How to configure VESPA_HOME for centos7?

Tags: vespa

Proton documentation says that http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/proton.html all data will be stored at $VESPA_HOME/var/db/vespa/search/

While we install the vespa from yum

```
echo "Installing Vespa"
yum -y install yum-utils epel-release
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/vespa/vespa/repo/epel-7/group_vespa-vespa-epel-7.repo
yum -y install vespa bind-utils git
```

It sets env variable VESPA_HOME to "/opt/vespa"

How do we stop data going in /opt/vespa?
We need to setup VESPA_HOME as "/mnt1/vespa"

Tried, setting up manually and installing via yum after; doesn't work.

Do we have any other alternative to configure data directory out of "/opt/vespa"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the vespa RPM is not relocatable to anywhere else than /opt/vespa. After doing the installation steps that you outline above, you can create symlinks for var and logs like this

`ln -sf /mnt1/vespa/logs /opt/vespa/logs
ln -sf /mnt1/vespa/var /opt/vespa/var`

This will ensure that the data and logs are stored in your /mnt1/vespa directory.